# Can't connect through RDP with enterprise Admin

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

I have a Windows Server 2008 as part of a win2008 domain.

I can connect to it as the local admin with no problems.

But when I try to connect to it as the Enterprise Admin, it says that i have the wrong credentials. I can connect locally with the same credentials and experience no problems.

I Included said enterprise admin to the remote desktop user group but no luck.

I am trying to use only one concurrent user so my guess is that it's not a limit problem.

Thanks

UPDATE:

The following is an error from a MACOSX RDP Client, but the same exact error shows on MSTSC.exe both in win7 and win8.1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q36O.png

I also tried as suggested:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhYOa.png

And the same results appear.

What is getting me confused is that if I login "Physically" with the same credentials, I can login and do my job.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried logging in with the username in the domain\user format?

Comment: Yes I have and still I receive the invalid credentials error.

Comment: Are the two IPs you are trying to connect to in the screenshots both the server you want?

Comment: In both screenshots I am Trying to connect to the same server through local network. The difference is the way I input the login credentials.

Comment: No in the first screenshot you are trying to connect to `192.168.0.214` and in the second you are trying to connect to `192.168.0.213` at least it says so in the error messages in the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect locally with the same credentials because the local and domain users are different users. If you don't specify the domain when logging on with the Administrator user account then Windows will "assume" the local Administrator user account.

Log on with ADdomain\Administrator to log on with the domain Administrator account

Log on with Administrator or .\Administrator to log on with the local Administrator account

Comment: +1 - And if this isn't the case, then the OP needs to make sure the credentials are right or post the exact error and more details.

Comment: I can connect locally as ADdomain\Administrator. But I can't use the same credentials through RDP. It will throw an invalid credentials error.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise admins are not automatically added to the local admin group when it joins the domain, unlike the domain admins. I suggest you add them to the remote desktop user group, that should fix the problem.